# Extracting part of a string with irregular delimiters in python

Tags: python, regex

I am wanting to extract the last part of the name of the file that is delimited by a constant prefix and '.csv'

Name of the file might look like:

> constant_prefix_**my file name**.csv

or

> constant_prefix_**myfilename**.csv

I would like to extract the values marked in bold into a variable.

Please advise.

Comment: Pretty simple regex: `_(.*?)\.csv$`.

Comment: @HamZa that will catch `filename` from `not_prefixed_filename.csv` too, so you have to add, the prefix, like I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script:

```
import re

name1 = 'constant_prefix_my file name.csv'
name2 = 'constant_prefix_myfilename.csv'

def get_name(string):
    return re.findall(r'constant_prefix_(my.*)\.csv', string)[0]
```

Demo:

```
print get_name(name1)
print get_name(name2)
```

Output:

```
my file name
myfilename
```

Or you can do this:

```
names = [get_name(n) for n in [name1, name2]]
print names
```

Output:

```
['my file name', 'myfilename']
```

Answer (score 1):

use `str.split` and `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> import os
>>> prefix = 'constant_prefix'

# if your prefix includes the trailing `_` then don't use `_` in `str.split`
# i.e just use this : `strs.split(prefix)[-1]`

>>> name, ext = os.path.splitext(strs.split(prefix + '_')[-1])
>>> name
'myfilename'

>>> strs = "constant_prefix_my file name.csv"
>>> name, ext = os.path.splitext(strs.split(prefix + '_')[-1])
>>> name
'my file name'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name1 = 'constant_prefix_my file name.csv'
name2 = 'constant_prefix_myfilename.csv'

constant_prefix = 'constant_prefix_'

name1 = name1[len(constant_prefix):-4] # 'my file name'
name2 = name2[len(constant_prefix):-4] # 'myfilename'
```